# Create new Numpy 3D by 3 Numpy arrays 3D

Tags: numpy

I have problems with the code. clahe_slices3 content saved in 3D. I want the content of clahe_slices1 to be saved in the first dimension, clahe_slices2 in the second dimension, and clahe_slices3 in the third dimension. In clahe_slices, here for your information is the shape of each one: clahe_slices.shape=(240,240,155) clahe_slices1.shape=(240,240,155) clahe_slices2.shape=(240,240,155) clahe_slices3.shape=(240,240,155) my code

```
nifti_img = nib.load(file_path)

        # Get the image data
img_data = nifti_img.get_fdata()

def apply_filter_to_nifti_image(img_data):

     clahe_slices = np.zeros_like(img_data)

     clahe_slices1 = np.zeros_like(img_data)

     clahe_slices2 = np.zeros_like(img_data)

     clahe_slices3 = np.zeros_like(img_data)

        

        
    for i in range(img_data.shape[0]):
    # Assuming the slice dimension is the first dimension
        clahe_slices[i, :, :] = clahe_slices1[i, :, :]
    for i in range(img_data.shape[1]):
        # Assuming the slice dimension is the second dimension
        clahe_slices[:, i, :] = clahe_slices2[:, i, :]
    for i in range(img_data.shape[2]):
        # Assuming the slice dimension is the third dimension
        clahe_slices[:, :, i] = clahe_slices3[:, :, i]

    

    # Example usage:
    return clahe_slices
apply_filter_to_nifti_image(img_data)
```

I have filtered the slides but when editing the dimension must be specified like this and when I select the dimension it filters the other dimensions but does not check that the slide content in the other dimensions is empty and therefore there are problems with the result.
That's why I thought about applying the filter and selecting the dimension each time, and in the end I combine the results of each dimension to get the correct results. Here, when I specify this, it does not save the result of clahe_slices1 and clahe_slices2, but only the result of the last loop in all dimensions. I'm still new to nifti anf numpy.
Please give me a solution to this matter, thank you
The code is too long and I only highlighted the important elements in the problem
I have problems with the code. clahe_slices3 content saved in all dimensions in clahe_slices. I want the content of clahe_slices1 to be saved in the first dimension, clahe_slices2 in the second dimension, and clahe_slices3 in the third dimension. In clahe_slices,

I expected a 3D array to be formed from the first dimensional slices of claheslices1, the second dimensional slices of claheslices2, and the third dimensional slices of claheslices3.  But the result I got in claheslices is slices of all special dimensions claheslices3

Comment: Plz fix the provided code, especially regarding its indentation. Also you have a return statement but no function. This is not valid Python code.

Comment: @OskarHofmann The code is too long, so I tried to simplify it by focusing on the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, and I suspect you don't have a clear picture either.  I'd suggest you test these ideas with a smaller example,such as  (4,5) 2d shape.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to replicate the `apply...` function in a small (3,3) array.  Make the `res` recipient array, and two like sized ones with distinct values:

```
In [38]: res = np.zeros((3,3)); res1 = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3); res2 = np.arange(10,100,10).reshape(3,3)

In [39]: res,res1,res2
Out[39]: 
(array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]),
 array([[10, 20, 30],
        [40, 50, 60],
        [70, 80, 90]]))
```

Apply the first iteration:

```
In [40]: for i in range(3): res[i,:] = res1[i,:]
In [41]: res
Out[41]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [7., 8., 9.]])
```

This just copies all rows of `res1` over.

Then copy all columns from `res2`.  To make it more interesting lets '+=' instead of just copy:

```
In [42]: for i in range(3): res[:,i] += res2[:,i]
In [43]: res
Out[43]: 
array([[11., 22., 33.],
       [44., 55., 66.],
       [77., 88., 99.]])
```

This the same as adding the two arrays:

```
In [44]: res1+res2
Out[44]: 
array([[11, 22, 33],
       [44, 55, 66],
       [77, 88, 99]])
```

I don't think you have a clear understanding of what  `formed from the first dimensional slices of claheslices1, the second dimensional slices of claheslices2,..` means.

All the first dimensional slices of an array are the whole array.  Similarly all the second dimensional slices.

I could start with a 2 plane 3d array, and copy to separate planes.

```
In [45]: res = np.zeros((2,3,3))
In [46]: for i in range(3): res[0,i,:] = res1[i,:]
In [47]: for i in range(3): res[1,:,i] += res2[:,i]
In [48]: res
Out[48]: 
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9.]],

       [[10., 20., 30.],
        [40., 50., 60.],
        [70., 80., 90.]]])
```

Which is the same as `stack` or `np.array((res1,res2))`:

```
In [49]: np.stack((res1,res2))
Out[49]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[10, 20, 30],
        [40, 50, 60],
        [70, 80, 90]]])
```